# When using an Angular HttpInterceptor, RxJS BehaviorSubject isn't updating properly

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

I'm attempting to set up an HttpInterceptor in Angular 8 so I can alert my users when the front end can't reach the back end. I have it set up like so:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private errorCounterE = new BehaviorSubject(999);
    errorCounter1 = this.errorCounterE.asObservable();

    setErrorCounterE(ourvalue: number): void {
        console.log("setting value: " + ourvalue);
        this.errorCounterE.next(ourvalue);
    }


    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log("aaa: " + this.errorCounterE.getValue());

        return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(
                retry(1),
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {                  

                    console.log("ccc: " + this.errorCounterE.getValue());
                    this.setErrorCounterE(this.errorCounterE.getValue() + 1);
                    console.log("ddd: " + this.errorCounterE.getValue());                    

                    return throwError(errorMessage);
                })
            )}}
```

with my app.module providers set up like this:

```js
providers: [
        emailCallService,
        securityCallService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }
    ],
```

I'm calling it from a simple button push now, with the back end turned off (so it will for sure throw an error), in a component class like this:

```js
export class ActiveMachinesComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private ecs: emailCallService, private scs: securityCallService, private hei: HttpErrorInterceptor) {
    this.emailErrorCount = 54321;
  }

private emailErrorCount: number;

 ngOnInit() {   
    console.log("error counter is now..." + this.emailErrorCount);
    this.hei.errorCounter1.subscribe(ourcount => this.emailErrorCount = ourcount);
    console.log("error counter is now..." + this.emailErrorCount); 
  }


buttonpress(): any { 
    console.log("------------");
    this.hei.errorCounter1.subscribe(thatvalue => {
      this.emailErrorCount = thatvalue
    });
    let t = this.emailErrorCount;
    console.log(t);
    console.log("------------");

    //then call it
    this.ecs.checkEmailService().subscribe((result) => {
        [another component makes an http call here, returning an observable.] 
    })
}
```

On page load, the ngInit works as it should, printing off 54321 and then 999. The first button push call prints off 999 between the lines of dashes. As the call goes back into the intercept, the value goes from 999 to 1000 in the catchError clause, as it should.

The problem is that if I push the button a second time, the number printed between the dashed lines is again 999, even though it will print "aaa: 1000" as the first step in the intercept. I'm thinking this is somehow due to my component class getting an individual instance of the interceptor class, but I thought that providing that in root was supposed to take care of that problem and make it so there was only one instance for everybody to share.

My end goal here is to have my error interceptor count the various types of different errors it sees (404, 403, whatever) and alert the user at different times based on what it's seen. But I'm running the ngIf's out of my component class, which means I need to get my error counters visible to that class. Any suggestions? Have I set this up totally wrong?

Comment: 1.Since you are subscribing to an observable and not the original Subject you will always get the first value back. 2. your subscriptions look like you expect the callback to be executed on the line where you have your subscriptions set up, but that would be a fundamental missunderstanding. You cannot handle and think about this like syncronous code.

Comment: I've also tried subscribing to the subject itself, without luck. Other things that don't work include setting up a simple variable in the Inteceptor class and then either asking for it directly or via a method that returns it as an observable. All I really want to do is find out what the value of a variable is in a sibling class. I'm not sure why I'm having such trouble doing that!

Comment: Maybe put your logging inside the subscribe callback. That way we can at least rule out any problems with asyncronously